# SynchronizationContext used in asynchronous server methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-core, grpc

So I have an async grpc C# server that needs to do a lot of cross talk between server methods (eg, a streaming response value for a stream rpc could be generated from another rpc).

I have tried setting the SynchronizationContext to a single thread based context, but server methods still seem to be called from arbitrary threads.

How could I ensure that all server methods are called on the same thread, with async/await continuations also on the same thread?

For example, see the following RPC handler:

```
public override Task<ResponseProto> TestRpc(RequestProto request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    // Call shared instance method - could be called from
    // multiple concurrent grpc requests, or streamed responses etc
    SharedInstanceMethod();

    // This is different every call... making a cross-thread issue
    // when calling SharedInstanceMethod();
    int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; 
}
```

Note that in this example, SharedInstanceMethod() is a placeholder for a lot of other functions and other asynchronous events - I'm not looking to make SharedInstance thread safe.

Comment: Aren't you effectively saying that you don't want to use async? Async will by definition use a secondary thread in order to free up the primary request thread and the continuation will execute on whatever free thread is then free when it's time to finish the request.

Comment: That's not my understanding of async... I thought async simply meant the rest of the method (after await) is queued to run in the SynchronizationContex - (which could be multi threaded as in Asp.NET), but the Win Forms context for example will always queue in the UI thread, so you can update UI controls after await...

Comment: How is the `TestRpc` method called?

Comment: Its an implementation of a grpc handler. The class extends from the *ServiceBase class generated by the grpc compiler.

Comment: A single-threaded context should work just fine. A lot of server-based libraries/frameworks will call back on thread pool threads; you just have to marshal those callbacks to your context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get continuations to run on the same thread, you could use `JoinableTaskFactory.Run(() => ...)` [from vs-threading](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading), which sets a `SynchronizationContext` to achieve this.

A problem with this is that as soon as you hit a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` you will lose this context, and continuations will end up running back on the thread pool threads, so if you are calling 3rd party libraries then you cannot guarantee this behavior, and if they are following best practice, then they will likely be using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

But going back to your question, I don't think this is what you want. It sounds like you don't have an asynchronous workflow that needs to be forced to run synchronously on 1 thread (which is good, cause it's not ideal). You have a method that cannot be called concurrently and needs some synchronization around it, you should use `lock` and add a private static object field to lock on.